# Custom aggregate function inside a package

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, aggregate-functions, ora-00600

I'm trying to write a custom aggregate function in Oracle and group that function inside a package together with some other functions that I have. As an example (to simulate the problem I have) suppose my custom aggregation to do a summation of numbers looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SUM_AGGREGATOR_TYPE AS OBJECT (
    summation NUMBER,

    STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(agg_context IN OUT
       SUM_AGGREGATOR_TYPE) RETURN NUMBER,

    MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT SUM_AGGREGATOR_TYPE,
        next_number IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER,

    MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT SUM_AGGREGATOR_TYPE,
        para_context IN SUM_AGGREGATOR_TYPE) RETURN NUMBER,

    MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN SUM_AGGREGATOR_TYPE,
        return_value OUT NUMBER, flags IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
);
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY SUM_AGGREGATOR_TYPE IS

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(agg_context IN OUT
    SUM_AGGREGATOR_TYPE)
      RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    agg_context := SUM_AGGREGATOR_TYPE(NULL);
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;


  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(self IN OUT SUM_AGGREGATOR_TYPE,
    next_number IN NUMBER)
      RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    IF self.summation IS NULL THEN
        self.summation := next_number;
    ELSIF summation IS NOT NULL THEN
        self.summation := self.summation + next_number;
    END IF;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(self IN OUT SUM_AGGREGATOR_TYPE,
    para_context IN SUM_AGGREGATOR_TYPE)
      RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    self.summation := self.summation + para_context.summation;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(self IN SUM_AGGREGATOR_TYPE,
    return_value OUT NUMBER, flags IN NUMBER)
      RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    return_value := self.summation;
    return ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

END;
```

If I write the following function definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_SUM(input NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING SUM_AGGREGATOR_TYPE;
```

and corresponding type declaration to test:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VECTOR
IS
  TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

this statement:

```
select my_sum(column_value) from table(vector(1, 2, 1, 45, 22, -1));
```

gives the correct result of 70. However, creating a package with the function definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MY_FUNCTIONS AS
  FUNCTION MY_SUM(input NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING SUM_AGGREGATOR_TYPE;
END;
```

and calling it via:

```
select MY_FUNCTIONS.my_sum(column_value) from table(vector(1, 2, 1, 45, 22, -1));
```

explodes with

```
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [17090], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

Is it possible to have custom aggregate functions nested inside package declarations?

Comment: 'ORA-00600' usually indicates an Oracle bug - sometimes due to unexpected combinations of features. What exact Oracle version are you running?

Comment: I'm using Oracle 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.1.0).

Comment: Do you have any news on this issue? I have problems too, however, in my case the connection is aborted `ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel`. I guess this is even worse than the `ORA-00600`. When I check `SELECT * FROM ALL_PROCEDURES`, I can see that the user-defined aggregate has been correctly created and registered...

Comment: Nope, haven't heard anything back yet. I posted this error on the [Oracle forums.](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2137501&tstart=0) Feel free to follow up on my post there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oracle uses ORA-00600 to signal unhandled exceptions i.e. bugs.  The first argument indicates the exception; ORA-17090 is a generic "operation not allowed".  Frequently they are restricted to specific permutations of database version and OS platform.  Other times it just means we're doing something really unusual.

Does including a custom aggregate function inside a package count as "really unusual"?  Not sure.  Certainly we are permitted to include data cartridge functions in PL/SQL functions.  But user-defined aggregates are a special case of ODCI.  While the documentation has no explicit rule against packages all the examples implement the aggregate using `CREATE FUNCTION`.

So, what to do?  Well, ORA-00600 messages require the intervention of Oracle Support, as it needs a patch.   If you have a Support account you can [find out more about this particular issue here](https://support.oracle.com/CSP/ui/flash.html#tab=KBHome(page=KBHome&id=()),(page=KBNavigator&id=(bmDocID=29616.1&from=BOOKMARK&bmDocDsrc=KB&viewingMode=1143))).  You will need to raise an iTAR to get further resolution.  Otherwise I'm afraid you're probably out of luck.

Comment: Strange that this is not supported. I'll post this on the Oracle forums to see what they have to say.

Comment: Created Oracle forum post: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2137501&tstart=0 so that the Oracle guys can follow up on this.

Comment: Per a question I asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215415/how-to-debug-a-user-defined-aggregate-function-in-oracle-11g), it seems that a user defined aggregate function does work when you create just the function but does not work inside a package.  In my case (which is ~3 years later), there is no error given but it returns incorrect output.  So, to anyone else who, like me, stumbles upon this question: if your user defined aggregate functions isn't working in a package, try using just a function.

Comment: That is correct, defining the function outside of a package is the solution, however the whole point of using a package is to avoid pollution of the namespace by grouping related functions / procedures inside a package.